# Google Apps Script to Output a JSON Array into a row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having issue with last step of writing a javascript array to a Google Sheets row.

I realize that I the setValues() method requires a 2D array, but I'm missing something obvious I'm not sure what.

I'm dealing with this JSON response, and I want to write the rates[] array to a single row in a Google Sheet.

```
{
    "base": "CAD",
    "date": "2017-05-05",
    "rates": {
        "AUD": 0.98264,
        "CNY": 5.0123,
        "GBP": 0.56122,
        "HKD": 5.652,
    }
}
```

Last part of my google apps script is the following:

```
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1).setValues([rates]);
```

This gives the error:

> Cannot convert Array to Object[][]. (line 52, file "Code")

I then embed another set of parenthesis as I thought it was a mistake in my conversion to a 2D array:

```
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1).setValues([[rates]]);
```

But then I get the arary put all into a single cell. So my conversion to a 2D array is wrong.

Can anyone spot what I"m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Using the information that you have provided, the code to create the 2D array from the object can be created from the following code:

```
function converObjectToArray() {
  var innerArray,k,k2,obj,objRates,outerArray;

  obj = {
    "base": "CAD",
    "date": "2017-05-05",
    "rates": {
        "AUD": 0.98264,
        "CNY": 5.0123,
        "GBP": 0.56122,
        "HKD": 5.652,
    }
  }

  objRates = obj.rates;

  outerArray = [];

  for (k in obj) {

    if (k !== 'rates') {continue;}

    objRates = obj[k];
    Logger.log('obj.rates ' + JSON.stringify(obj.rates))

    innerArray = [];//reset

    for (k2 in objRates) {
      innerArray.push(objRates[k2]);
    }

    outerArray.push(innerArray);
  }

  Logger.log(outerArray)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create an array from the object and then write in the array into the spreadsheet using set values like so:

```
function addObject(){
 var obj = {
    "base": "CAD",
    "date": "2017-05-05",
    "rates": {
        "AUD": 0.98264,
        "CNY": 5.0123,
        "GBP": 0.56122,
        "HKD": 5.652,
    }
}
var inputArray = []
var rates = obj.rates
for (var j in rates){
  inputArray.push([j,rates[j]])
}
Logger.log(inputArray)
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('your Sheet Name');
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1,inputArray.length,inputArray[0].length).setValues(inputArray)

}
```

This code will also enter the value of key in the sheet.