# Remove extra characters around GPS request with Google Places API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-places-api

[See here for a working example of my Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VnawqIg7F4w2qp4zu5pjTcF8bACJ3Ks-wSBhyarfjFc/edit#gid=2100307022)

[Here is my Google Apps Script](https://script.google.com/home/projects/1gChb8LElBcb3imyA2yohDw6MB72l2D5sIPod0EbNL149bSrrRgKmsjAf/edit)

---

I have a side project that I use for traveling [which I have been working on for some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67875739/how-to-remove-unwanted-characters-brackets-quotes-and-commas-from-a-json-str). It makes use of the Google Places API in order to pull relevant data about a place and log it in a Google Sheet. From there, I take the Sheet and import it into a Google MyMap which creates an overlay on Google Maps which I can use to navigate and find information quickly.

I am trying to create individual functions for the various fields with which I want to fill in my Sheet. So there will be a separate function for business hours, address, Google Maps link, business website, etc.

When it comes to GPS coordinates, the coordinates return under the Geometry of a place and within the Location subsection.

[Here is an example](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJh9-J99hYwokRxc9AgwkG1Io&fields=name,formatted_address,geometry,formatted_phone_number,website,url,types,opening_hours&key=AIzaSyD1FOrIRLbO9mV4zbh6df0os6ZCeaGKlrE&locationbias=point:42.6408341747088,18.109130742689384) of BIG Alice Brewing:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "formatted_address" : "8-08 43rd Rd, Long Island City, NY 11101, USA",
      "formatted_phone_number" : "(347) 688-2337",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 40.75208620000001,
            "lng" : -73.9505873
         },
         "viewport" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 40.75347488029151,
               "lng" : -73.94919081970849
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 40.75077691970851,
               "lng" : -73.9518887802915
            }
         }
      },
      "name" : "Big aLICe Brewing",
      "opening_hours" : {
         "open_now" : true,
         "periods" : [
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 0,
                  "time" : "2000"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 0,
                  "time" : "1200"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 1,
                  "time" : "2100"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 1,
                  "time" : "1600"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 2,
                  "time" : "2100"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 2,
                  "time" : "1600"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 3,
                  "time" : "2100"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 3,
                  "time" : "1600"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 4,
                  "time" : "2100"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 4,
                  "time" : "1600"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 5,
                  "time" : "2200"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 5,
                  "time" : "1200"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 6,
                  "time" : "2200"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 6,
                  "time" : "1200"
               }
            }
         ],
         "weekday_text" : [
            "Monday: 4:00 – 9:00 PM",
            "Tuesday: 4:00 – 9:00 PM",
            "Wednesday: 4:00 – 9:00 PM",
            "Thursday: 4:00 – 9:00 PM",
            "Friday: 12:00 – 10:00 PM",
            "Saturday: 12:00 – 10:00 PM",
            "Sunday: 12:00 – 8:00 PM"
         ]
      },
      "types" : [ "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
      "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?cid=10003627310223249349",
      "website" : "http://bigalicebrewing.com/"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

**If I just want to return the GPS coordinates of `40.75208620000001, -73.9505873` what would I need to do in order to return that value without the extra**

```
`"lat" : 40.75208620000001,
            "lng" : -73.9505873`
```

**parts of the value?**

Below is my working code for how I return the rest of my values:

```
// This location basis is used to narrow the search -- e.g. if you were
// building a sheet of bars in NYC, you would want to set it to coordinates
// in NYC.
// You can get this from the url of a Google Maps search.
const LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON = "40.754734421655655, -73.98840133506883"; // e.g. "37.7644856,-122.4472203"

function COMBINED2(text) {
  var API_KEY = 'AIzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxlrE';
  var baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json';
  var queryUrl = baseUrl + '?input=' + text + '&inputtype=textquery&key=' + API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var placeId = JSON.parse(json);
  var ID = placeId.candidates[0].place_id;

  var fields = 'name,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number,website,url,types,opening_hours';
  var baseUrl2 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=';
  var queryUrl2 = baseUrl2 + ID + '&fields=' + fields + '&key='+ API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;

  if (ID == '') {
    return 'Give me a Google Places URL...';
  }

  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl2);
  var json2 = response2.getContentText();
  var place = JSON.parse(json2).result;

  var placeName = place.name;
  var placeAddress = place.formatted_address;
  var placePhoneNumber = place.formatted_phone_number;
  var placeWebsite = place.website;
  var placeURL = place.url;

  var weekdays = '';
  place.opening_hours.weekday_text.forEach((weekdayText) => {
    weekdays += ( weekdayText + '\r\n' );
  } );


  var data = [ [
    place.name,
    place.formatted_address,
    place.formatted_phone_number,
    place.website,
    place.url,
    weekdays.trim()
  ] ];

  return data;
}
```

---

**Completed Code**

I managed to incorporate Irvin's code as follows.

```
    function GPS(text) {

   //TEST PARSING
     var API_KEY = 'AIzaSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    var baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json';
    var queryUrl = baseUrl + '?input=' + text + '&inputtype=textquery&key=' + API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var placeId = JSON.parse(json);
    var ID = placeId.candidates[0].place_id;

    var fields = 'name,geometry,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number,website,url,types,opening_hours';
    var baseUrl2 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=';
    var queryUrl2 = baseUrl2 + ID + '&fields=' + fields + '&key='+ API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;
    
    var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl2); 
    var content = responseAPI.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content.toString()); //Sample JSON parsing

    //An array variable to contain the longitude and latitude data
    var inputArray = []; 
    //Parse the "location" JSON array contents
    var gpsCoord = json.result.geometry.location

    //Place the JSON contents into the array variable
    for (var j in gpsCoord){ 
      inputArray.push([gpsCoord[j]]); 
    }
    return inputArray.join(", "); 


}
```

Comment: Here's a link to my answer [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Suggestion

You can try placing the JSON array values of "result.geometry.location" into an array variable on your Apps Script code. You can refer to this sample script below & then adjust your script accordingly:

### Sample Script:

```
 function gpsCoordinate() {
    //TEST PARSING
    var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJh9-J99hYwokRxc9AgwkG1Io&fields=name,formatted_address,geometry,formatted_phone_number,website,url,types,opening_hours&key=AIzaSyD1FOrIRLbO9mV4zbh6df0os6ZCeaGKlrE&locationbias=point:42.6408341747088,18.109130742689384"); 
    var content = responseAPI.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content.toString()); //Sample JSON parsing

    //An array variable to contain the longitude and latitude data
    var inputArray = []; 
    //Parse the "location" JSON array contents
    var gpsCoord = json.result.geometry.location

    //Place the JSON contents into the array variable
    for (var j in gpsCoord){ 
      inputArray.push([gpsCoord[j]]); 
    }
    return inputArray; 
  }
```

> Note: Used the code from [Google Apps Script to Output a JSON Array into a row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43836190) as reference

### Sample Result:

> The `gpsCoordinate()` method only returned the longitude & latitude values from the JSON result:

[image]

Comment: Legend. Thanks so much for that. I incorporated it just fine. Made one small change to your return line as I was getting the longitude in one cell and latitude beneath it. Wrote it as `return inputArray.join(", ")` so it's one GPS cell which will get pulled into MyMaps to form the address.